# Entity not resolved in code first DataService with Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm making a DataService with Entity Framework 4.1 using Code First POCO objects.  I can access the data fine when I create an instance of MyEntityContext and access it directly, however when I try and access the DataService over HTTP it breaks with the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: The given name 'Department' was not found in the entity sets.
```

I've tried all sorts of things but keep coming back to the same problem.  Not sure what could be wrong.

Department is the only Entity I am mapping currently.  It is defined as follows:

```
[Table("tb_department")]
public class Department
{        
    [Key]
    [Column("department_no", TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Column("department_name", TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

My data context looks like this:

```
public class MyEntityContext : DbContext
{
    public MyEntityContext(string connStr)
        : base(connStr)
    {
    }

    public MyEntityContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

And my service looks like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class MyDataService : DataService<MyEntityContext>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Department", EntitySetRights.AllRead);            
    }

    protected override MyEntityContext CreateDataSource()
    {
        MyEntityContext ctx = new MyEntityContext(
            Utility.GenerateConnStr
        );

        return ctx;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it says "Department" was not found in the entity sets and your entity set name is "Departments" so try pluralizing the call.